# get value from php/mysql autocompletion

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have some script to search city on table city from mysql database.
Everything works but when the result displaying I would like when I click on result, display this on my input search. 
An idea to helping me ?

JQUERY

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#search_results").slideUp();
    $("#button_find").click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        search_ajax_way();
    });
    $("#search_query").keyup(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        search_ajax_way();
    });

});

function search_ajax_way() {
    $("#search_results").show();
    var search_this = $("#search_query").val();
    $.post("mod/search.php", {
        searchit: search_this
    }, function(data) {
        $("#display_result").html(data);

    })
}
</script>
```

PHP

```
$term = strip_tags(substr($_POST['searchit'], 0, 100));
$term = utf8_decode($term);
$term = mysql_escape_string($term); // Attack Prevention
$query = mysql_query("select distinct city from city where (city like '{$term}%') order by city limit 10 ");

if (mysql_num_rows($query)) {
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
        echo ''.utf8_encode($row['city']).
        '<BR>';

    }
} else {
    echo 'No result';
}
```

HTML

```
<input type="text" style="width:60%;margin-right:10px;" name="search_query" id="search_query" value="" autocomplete="off">
<div id="display_result"></div>
```

Comment: you can use `typeahead`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to output the individual cities in an element rather than just separated by `<br>`'s and then need to listen to `delegated` events for the `onclick`

e.g.

PHP:

```
echo "<ul>";
if (mysql_num_rows($query)) {
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
        echo '<li class="search-city">'.utf8_encode($row['city']).
        '</li>';

    }
} else {
    echo '<li>No result</li>';
}

echo '</ul>';
```

Then in javascript you need to listen to delegated events as the elements aren't there from the beginning of the page load when the javascript is first interpreted. https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

So you need to do something like this:

Javascript:

```
$(document).on("click", "li.search-city", function(){
    // Now do whatever you want with the clicked value
    console.log($(this).val());
});
```